# Conditionally override all routes (MVC / ASP)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that connects to a DB via a Web Service.

If the WebService is not contactable, I want to redirect the user to a page explaining the service isn't running.  Currently it just crashes when the WebService doesnt respond properly.

What is the best method to achieve this?  I have lots of controllers so writing error trapping code for each function in each controller for this specific case would be tedious and involve a lot of code repeation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy option is to write a base-controller; override the methods you want (whether that is *before* the call (`OnActionExecuting`) or *upon exception* (`OnException`)), and just add `: MyBaseController` to each controller.

Another option would be to decorate each controller with a filter-attribute that does the same work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HandleError` attribute on the controller to catch the specific exceptions and redirect to an error page. You can also inherit from it and override the `OnException` method with custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

Found a great tutorial [here](http://www.davidjuth.com/asp-net-mvc-error-handler.aspx) on it.
Implemented it and it all works as expected on a global level.  Great!

**Update:**
Actually that only helped with 404's and didnt handle them properly.
I managed to find another question here on stackoverflow that answers it perfectly - find the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a base controllor and override OnException
     protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) i.e will be 
Catch block for all exceptions in Controller Actions